# Proof of Début Theorem for right-continuous adapted process - III

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, proof-explanation, random, stopping-times

I miss one step in understanding the proof of the Debut theorem for right-continuous adapted processes [as it is given here](https://almostsuremath.com/2009/11/15/stopping-times-and-the-debut-theorem/#scn_st_thm2). This is my problem. Given a process $X$ consider the random time
$$
S = \inf\left\{t\geq 0 \left| \sup_{0\leq u\leq t}X_u\geq K\right.\right\},
$$
where $K$ is a real constant. The proof says that the event $\{S\leq t\}$ is equivalent to the event $\{\forall\varepsilon>0\exists 0\leq s\leq t|X_s>K-\varepsilon\}$. I am really struggling in understanding why so any advice is warmly welcome.

**ADDENDUM** It is probably more intuitive this formulation of the problem. Let $f$ be a function and let

$$x_0=\inf\left\{y\geq 0\left|\sup_{0\leq z\leq y}f(z)\geq K\right.\right\}.$$

Therefore

$$x_0\leq x\Leftrightarrow \forall\varepsilon>0\exists x^{\prime}\in[0,x]:f(x^{\prime})>K-\varepsilon$$

Comment: You want to show the events are equivalent, so you need to show each is contained in the other.  Are you able to figure out either containment?

Comment: @user6247850 none of them, unfortunately.

Comment: @user6247850 Actually the implication $\Leftarrow$ is not difficult. Suppose that $\forall\varepsilon>0\exists x^{\prime}\in[0,x]:f(x^{\prime})>K-\varepsilon$ then you have that $\sup_{0\leq z\leq x}f(z)\geq K$ which means that $x\in\left\{y\geq 0\left|\sup_{0\leq z\leq y}f(z)\geq K\right.\right\}$ and being $x_0$ the maximum of the upper bounds of the set in which $x$ is included, we have $x_0\leq x$.

Comment: Yes, that is right.  I would argue that the other direction is even easier if you want to give it a shot.

Comment: @user6247850 I tired by contradiction. Call $E=\left\{y\geq 0\left|\sup_{0\leq z\leq y}f(z)\geq K\right.\right\}$. Suppose that $\exists\varepsilon>0:\forall x^{\prime}\in[0,x]\Rightarrow f(x^{\prime})\leq K-\varepsilon<K$. Therefore for all $y\in E$ we have $x\leq y$, so $x$ is a lower bound for $E$ and so $x\leq x_0$. This is almost fine, but shouldnt I get $x<x_0$, which is the negation of $x_0\leq x$ ?

Comment: I think the step you're missing is that, since $f$ is right-continuous, that set $E$ is closed.